# esp_https_ota.h: No such file or directory

Tags: esp32

I am working on a ESP32 project that required firmware update, so i am using the following

```html
void update_fwm(void)
{
    esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .url = "https://myserver.net/firmware/ESP32/Device1/fmw.bin",
        //.cert_pem = (char *)server_cert_pem_start,
    };
    esp_err_t ret = esp_https_ota(&config);
    if (ret == ESP_OK) {
        esp_restart();
    } else {
        return ESP_FAIL;
    }
    return ESP_OK;

}
```

When i preform a build i get the followin:

```html
../main/azure_iot_freertos_esp32_main.c:10:10: fatal error: esp_https_ota.h: No such file or directory
 #include "esp_https_ota.h"
```

If I understood it correctly with ESP32 IDF, all libraries are inbuild into the compiler?

Is there reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Without further details I assume that there is propably a problem with your toolchain (linking). If the setup is done correctly this esp-lib should be "found".

Please refer to the official Espressif documentation for the correct setup of the toolchain on your system:  [Espressif Get Started](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/index.html#installation)

If used in a (self-written) component, make sure to use `REQUIRES <lib>` in the CMakeLists-file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need `REQUIRES esp_https_ota` in `CMakeLists.txt` if you are also using `set(COMPONENTS "main")`.